# Calculating exponents recursively. Getting overflow exception

Tags: java, recursion

I have to calculate x^n recursively and I had no problem with that. I also had to implement a more efficient method when n is even using, x^n = ( x^n/2 )^2. Maybe I didn't implement it right but when It seems to be giving me a overflow error.

```
public static double exponent(double x, int n){
    if(n < 1){
        return 1;
    }else{ 

    if(n % 2 ==0){
            return x *power(x, (n/2)*(n/2));
        }else{
            return x * power(x, n-1);
        }
        }
```

Comment: No, you didn't implement it right.  It's (x^(n/2))^2, not (x^((n/2)^2)), but the second one is what you implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Your case for the even power `n` is incorrect.  Your return statement is equivalent to x * x<sup>n<sup>2</sup>/4</sup>.

Instead, pass `n/2` as the exponent to the recursive call, and square it before returning it.  Use the fact that x<sup>n</sup> = (x<sup>n/2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>.

```
double y = power(x, n/2);
return y * y;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return x *power(x, (n/2)*(n/2));
```

should be

```
double tmp = power(x, n/2)
return tmp * tmp;
```